# WW_MOUSE_LL hook doesnt get called

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010, mouse-hook

Im currently creating a AFKChecker for my application.
The problem is that the low level mouse hook doesnt get called.
I have checked if it returns 0 which it doesnt.
So the keyboard hook works but not the mouse hook.
I have googled, but I have still not found a solution for my problem.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace AFKChecker
{
    public static class ActivityChecker
    {
        public static Int64 LastKeypress = 0;
        public static int AFKTime = 300;

        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        public const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;
        private static HookProc _keyproc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _keyhookID = IntPtr.Zero;
        private static HookProc _mouseproc = HookCallback;
        private static IntPtr _mousehookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        public static void AddHook()
        {
            LastKeypress = Tools.UnixTime();
            _keyhookID = SetKeyboardHook(_keyproc);
            _mousehookID = SetKeyboardHook(_mouseproc);
        }

        private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            LastKeypress = Tools.UnixTime();
            return CallNextHookEx(_keyhookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        public static void RemoveHook()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_keyhookID);
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(_mousehookID);
        }

        public static Boolean IsAFK()
        {
            return (LastKeypress + AFKTime > Tools.UnixTime());
        }

        private static IntPtr SetKeyboardHook(HookProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private static IntPtr SetMouseHook(HookProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
                    GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        private delegate IntPtr HookProc(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
    }
}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are not calling `SetMouseHook`, re-check your `AddHook()` function:

```
    public static void AddHook()
    {
        LastKeypress = Tools.UnixTime();
        _keyhookID = SetKeyboardHook(_keyproc);
        _mousehookID = SetKeyboardHook(_mouseproc); // SetMouseHook() here?
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Installing a mouse/keyboard hook just to find the idle time of the user strikes me as conceptually wrong. This should only be the last resort if windows doesn't offer any better API.

A [quick search](http://www.google.de/search?rls=en&q=user+idle+time+windows) reveals the [GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx) API which is designed for this purpose. And a codeproject article describing how to do that in C#: [Getting the user idle time with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GetIdleTimeWithCS.aspx)